# Tengo 32 diccionarios y necesito cambiar las comillas de cada objeto, ya que están mal puestas, co un replace o algo así,se puede?

Tags: pycharm

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y estamos trabajando con 400 y resto de archivos, la mayoría de esos se hicieron mal y las comillas se colocaron de manera errónea, ¿hay alguna manera para no tener que ir remplazando una por una y hacerlo con alguna función en Python que me reemplace las comillas mal colocadas por unas bien puestas?.

Ejm:

```
{“nombre”:”Buffon”,”numero”:”00”,”tiempojugado”:”123”,”amarillas”:”2”,”goles”:”6”,”posición”:”Portero”}
```

Se puso las mismas comillas y quiero saber si se pueden remplazar por estas `""` ya que en los diccionarios están puestas las de cierre en los dos lados.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado esto en la net, espero y te sirva.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.